# How are web service implementation classes discovered according JAX-WS spec?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jax-ws

I'm interested, how Java EE / JAX-WS specification (or Weblogic in general) handles situation, where there is `@WebService` annotated web service implementation classes in a library jar either in...

- APP-INF/lib directory (EAR level)
- WEB-INF/lib directory (WAR level)
- EAR root with EJB's MANIFEST.MF Class-path entries pointing at them

By the JAX-WS specification considering all three possibilites, should Weblogic discover and host these services, ignore them or is the behavior undefined?

And more importantly, how to configure the behavior? Ultimately, I don't want those web services hosted but they are, and I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or misconfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment of web services is defined by [JSR-109 Implementing Enterprise Web Services 1.4 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr109/index3.html) in Chapter 8 "Deployment".

It says:

> Validation of the artifact packaging is performed to ensure that:
>
> - Every port in every WSDL defined in the Web services deployment descriptor has a corresponding port-component element.
> - JAX-RPC or JAX-WS service components are only packaged within a WAR file.
> - Stateless or Singleton session bean Web services are only packaged within an EJB-JAR or WAR file.
> - The WSDL bindings used by the WSDL ports are supported by the Web Services for Java EE runtime. Bindings that are not supported may be declared within the WSDL if no port uses them.

What this means is that your server should only be finding these services if they have been deployed as part of a WAR, or (if they have been annotated with @Singleton or @Stateless or configured in deployment descriptors) as part of an EJB module.

They are part of the WAR if they appear in its WEB-INF/lib directory.

The presence of such jars in an EAR's `APP-INF/lib` directory is unspecified as the directory is a WebLogic extension that dates back to sometime in the 00s. You should avoid using that and just place utility jars in the EAR file's `lib` directory.

In any event, if your server is deploying web services from anywhere else other than a WAR file (and they're definitely not EJBs) then you need to complain to your vendor.

Comment: Are the classes inside JAR regarded as part of the WAR or EJB, if MANIFEST.MF file of the WAR or EJB references the JAR in Class-path entry (regardless where the JAR resides)? I suspect this is the case, because in my case **every** web module tries to host the same service from the JAR.

Comment: The specifications talk about finding annotated services within EJB-JARs or within WAR files. When a jar contains a Manifest Class-Path entry,  the classes in each of the referenced jars become visible to the classes in that jar only. I would not expect it to change annotation scanning

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how libraries were packaged inside the EAR. In the starting point, all libraries resided on the EAR root and dependent modules (WARs, EJBs) referenced them by the `Class-Path` attribute of their `MANIFEST.MF`. For some bizzare reason, these libraries were listed even on the EAR's `MANIFEST.MF` and I don't really know why.

Apparently, from Weblogic point of view this is the same as the library contained resources would reside *in the module itself*, thus annotations and other configuration are discovered automatically by the container per each module which references the library. I'm not exactly sure this is the case, but I believe so and try confirm it.

After moving libraries to `APP-INF/lib`, no annotations or configuration are discovered from the library.